# Instalação de pacotes no Rstudio

Tags: r

Não consigo instalar nenhum pacote do Rstudio no meu notebook. Alguém sabe o que devo fazer?
Aparece esta mensagem abaixo:

[image: 1]]

Comment: Se o problema persistir depois de realizar a sugestão do Alexandre( mais indicado ), pode tentar fazer a instalação manual dos pacotes, guia `Packages->install`, pode utilizar o repositório do CRAN ou realizar o download do pacote em formato .zip, .gz, .tar etc e instalar a partir do local, [aqui](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adicionando-pacotes-rstudio-manualmente-rodrigo-rosa-da-silva/) você encontra um tutorial de como adicionar pacotes manualmente.

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema esteja no anti-virus, você precisa conceder permissão do programa acessar as pastas

Answer (score 2):

Tens de alterar as permissões da pasta indicada (partindo do princípio que tens permissão para isso):

- vai até à pasta em causa
- Clica com o botão direito do rato no ícone da mesma
- Escolhe "Propriedades"
- Separador "Segurança"
- Grupo "Utilizadores"
- Clica em "Editar"
- Selecciona todas as caixas que não estão seleccionadas de forma a permitir as acções correspondentes

Em princípio tal irá resolver o problema.

Alternativamente experimenta executar o RStudio como administrador (embora a primeira solução seja a mais desejável).